# jquery ui autocomplete: how to match "whitespace" separated query with accurate "comma" separated record

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have  **preloaded** xml records on the client side, on which **jquery ui autocomplete** is applied.
Say there is a record like this one: **"car,bike,plane"**.

Currently (while using **jquery ui autocomplete**) if a user types : **"car,bike"** --> it will find the record mentioned above.

However if the user types: **"car bike"** (which means instead of **comma, a whitespace** ) --> no results will be displayed.

How to match "car bike" with the given "comma" separated record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the peeps who might be dealing with the same situation, here is the **solution** i came up with, a brief explanation first:

- First, i  **split** the search term (query) on white space
- I then dynamically build a regex definition by concatenating the  **splitted words** with some more regex attributes. **For example**: say user searches for **"Car Bike"** --> after splitting i dynamically build the following string:
  [*str = **"Car"**+(any character(s))+**"Bike"**+(any character(s))*] , which is then fed to javascript **RegExp**.

To make it more clear, here is my **Code:(hopefully it might help you)**

```
$( "#field" ).autocomplete({
         source:function(request, response) {
         var query_array = request.term.toUpperCase().split(/\s+/g);//split on white space
         if(query_array.length >1)// if two ore more words, separated by whitespace
         {
           if(!/^\s*$/.test(query_array[query_array.length-1]))//if last word is not only whitespace
             {
                var new_query = '';
                for (var i=0; i<query_array.length; ++i )
                {
                   new_query+='(\\b' +query_array[i]+'\\b)';//word boundaries
                   if(i<query_array.length-1)
                   {
                     new_query+="([\\s\\S\\.]*)";// match ALL characters including newline , * is for many
                   }
                }

                 var matcher = new RegExp('^'+new_query, "g");//must Start with query term, apply regex global
                 var a = $.grep( autocomplete_data_array, function(item,index){
                               return matcher.test(item.value);
                     });

                 if(a.length>0)
                 {
                   response(a);
                 }
               }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can split the two arrays and loop one of them searching the index of the looped items at the other array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var str="car,bike,plane";
    var strToSearch= "car bike";


    var splitted = str.split(",");
    var strToSearchSplitted = strToSearch.split(' ');
    var found = false;

    for (var i in splitted){
      if (strToSearchSplitted.indexOf(splitted[i]) != -1){
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
<script>
```

Comment: thanks for your help bro, i did split but used different way, check my answer if u want.